# What Is -[NSURL _fastCharacterContents]:?

Tags: ios, ipad, nsstring, init, cfstring

So I'm calling this in a method:

```
-(id)initWithContentURL:(NSString *)url {
if (self = [super init]) {
    NSLog(@"xSheetMusicViewController - %@",url);
    // Casting an NSString object pointer to a CFStringRef:
    CFStringRef cfString = (CFStringRef)url;        
    CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), cfString, NULL, NULL);
    pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Which crashes right at the NSLog at the line marked:

```
CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), cfString, NULL, NULL);
```

with this wonderful little error I've never seen before.  Here's the crash log:

```
SheetMuse[83550:b603] -[NSURL _fastCharacterContents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4ec35f0
2011-09-22 17:36:22.921 SheetMuse[83550:b603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL _fastCharacterContents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4ec35f0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x011be5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01312313 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x011c00bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0112f966 ___forwarding___ + 966
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0112f522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
5   CoreFoundation                      0x010d2857 CFStringGetCharactersPtr + 135
6   CoreFoundation                      0x010d6c93 CFStringGetFileSystemRepresentation + 35
7   CoreFoundation                      0x01110811 _CFFindBundleResources + 289
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0110d961 CFBundleCopyResourceURL + 305
9   SheetMuse                           0x00005b19 -[xSheetMusicViewController initWithContentURL:] + 153
10  SheetMuse                           0x00009724 -[ExamplesViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 708
11  UIKit                               0x00487b68 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1140
12  UIKit                               0x0047db05 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
13  Foundation                          0x00b9779e __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
14  CoreFoundation                      0x0119f8c3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
15  CoreFoundation                      0x011a0e74 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
16  CoreFoundation                      0x010fd2c9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
17  CoreFoundation                      0x010fc840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
18  CoreFoundation                      0x010fc761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
19  GraphicsServices                    0x028a31c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
20  GraphicsServices                    0x028a3289 GSEventRun + 115
21  UIKit                               0x0041ec93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
22  SheetMuse                           0x000028a9 main + 121
23  SheetMuse                           0x00002825 start + 53
)
terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
```

So, what is this error, and how do I fix it?

EDIT: This question has been solved.  Thank you everyone who answered, I was banging my head on the wall trying to figure this out.  If you would like, I can give you a mention in the app, seeing as I would like to release it in a few weeks, and your help has ironed out the biggest bug in the code.  Again THANK YOU!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-_fastCharacterContents:` is a private method of `NSString`. The error you get indicates that the corresponding message was being sent to an `NSURL` instance, hence the crash. It looks like the `url` parameter that’s being passed to `-initWithContentURL:` is an `NSURL`, not an `NSString`.

Placing

```
NSLog(@"url is of type %@", [url class]);
```

at the beginning of the method should tell you the exact class of `url`.

I suggest you change your method signature to:

```
- (void)initWithContentPath:(NSString *)path
```

in order to make it clear that the method expects a string representing a (relative) path. There are other classes in Cocoa Touch that declare  `-initWithContentURL:` to receive an `NSURL *` argument.

Comment: Actually, you were completely right!  The NSLog returned "is of type NSURL."  Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, check the edit,  I want your express Permission before I do anything.

Comment: @Cod I’d rather not. Upvoting is enough. :)

Comment: OK, again, thanks so much!  

P.S. I needed to call stringWithString in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases this sort of error is due to passing the wrong type of object on a call.

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling initWithContentURL? It looks like you might be passing an NSURL that has been (improperly) cast to an NSString.